# Convert C# DateTime into GregorianCalendar date

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.forms

How to convert the dotnet C# DateTime with millisecond into equivalent value of Java.util.date time object with the millisecond value

I have following code sample.

```
DateTime cdate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01);
cdate.AddMilliseconds(100);
```

I need this c# date into java.util.date object with the same millisecond.

```
Java.Util.GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar() { Time = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) };

     date.Set((cdate.Year), (cdate.Month-1), cdate.Day, cdate.Hour, cdate.Minute, cdate.Second);
```

But I can't able to get the Millisecond. I need to get the millisecond also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java we set milliseconds to Calendar (GregorianCalendar is Calendar) this way

```
Calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
date.add(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, cdate.Millisecond);